# Cytoscape.js: How to export node colors/shapes/size to json?

Tags: javascript, json, cytoscape.js

I've got a cytoscape.js viewport where users can set colors(and shapes) of specific nodes. These networks, along with the colors the user picked, I would like to export.

cy.json() and cy.style().json() return the initial state of the nodes.

Right now I'm adding a new attribute "current_color" to a node each time a color is changed, which is exported by cy.json().

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using mappers and putting the custom colours etc in `ele.data()`, you should be able to import/export everything pretty easily.

Comment: It seems that, for the time being, this is the most straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `ele.renderedStyle( name )` ?

According to [documentation](http://js.cytoscape.org/#ele.renderedStyle) this will

> Get a particular rendered style property value

I see that this function will not work on the entire graph. Maybe you can export the json and then work on the resulting string by replacing the values from ele.renderedStyle('background-color')

Comment: `ele.renderedStyle( name )` didn't work, though `ele.style( name )` gives me the current background-color.

Currently the most efficient solution I have is, prior to exporting, run over each element and add the style to the json object using `ele.data('current_color', ele.style('background-color'));`

Comment: Sounds like `renderedStyle()` is only for numerical values currently.  If you'd create a github issue for this, support for other types could probably be added.  Thanks!

Comment: Issue about this filed on GitHub